# React Router v5 - Get the template of the current route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to get the route template corresponding to the current URL. If I use `useRouteMatch` hook outside component that corresponding to current route, it returns root route (`/`). How to get most nested route template from top level components?